# Scraping more no of pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, pycharm

I am scraping amazon site so i started to scrap books which consists of total 75 pages (1200 products) when i run program it stops at random pages (i think 10 - 20 pages) by just crawling 200 - 400 products.
Hear is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def amazon_cat(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://www.amazon.in/s/ref=sr_pg_2?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A976389031%2Cp_n_feature_three' \
          '_browse-bin%3A9141482031&page=' + str(page) + '&bbn=976389031&ie=UTF8&qid=1468676695&lo=stripbooks'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soap = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
        for links in soap.findAll('h2',
                              {'class': 'a-size-medium a-color-null s-inline  s-access-title  a-text-normal'}):
            value = links.get('data-attribute')
            # link = links.get('herf')
            # link = parse.urljoin('http://www.amazon.in', link)
            with open('valuess.txt', 'a') as file:
                file.write(value + '\n')
            print(value)
        page += 1


amazon_cat(75)
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Also check if the `while` condition is not getting satisfied.

Comment: when i try to print page no's along with data some pages are skipping. For example. DATA 1 DATA 2 DATA 3 4 5 6 DATA 7 DATA 8 9 10 DATA ........... and so on like that that means it is mot crawling 4 5 6 pages that was my problem. And no error message is displaying

Comment: Print the value of `page` after each iteration and see where it stops.